# WPF Image - server returned Forbidden (403)

Tags: c#, wpf, image, binding

I have a `ListView` binded to an `ObservableCollection`. This ListView uses an ItemTemplate which consists of only one `Image` control, which Source property is binded to a URL string.

For some URLs images fail to load because the remote server would return "Forbidden (403)" - this **could** be solved by adding a certain header to the HTTP request that gets the image, but the problem is I don't know how I should go about modifying said request.

I tried two different approaches:

1. Creating an `IValueConverter` object. I would take the URL and get image data myself - put it into a `MemoryStream` and use the stream to initialize a `BitmapImage` object and return that to the Image control. This approach proved to be really slow and it blocked the UI thread.
2. Creating a new property to bind to that would return a byte array containing image data. This data would be lazily initialized the first time it's called using a Task. When the data would finish downloading, the `PropertyChanged` event would be fired that would update the Image visually. This approach did not block the UI thread, but was extremely slow for some reason.

I want to know 2 things:

- **Why** are my approaches significantly slower?
- **How** do I directly modify the way Image control gets images from a remote server without affecting the performance/speed that much?

Consider the following example:

```
public byte[] ImageThumbnail 
{
    get 
    {
        if (img == null) img = GetImage(ImageUrls.Thumbnail);
        return img;
    }
}
public byte[] GetImage(string url) {
     HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
     // add some headers
     return client.GetByteArrayAsync(url).Result;
}
```

Image would be binded to "ImageThumbnail" with IsAsync set to True. The images are downloaded significantly slower in this case compared to just binding the URL directly to Image source.

Comment: "Why are my approaches significantly slower?" Nobody can tell that unless you show us your code. As a hint, you should probably use an asynchronous Binding (by setting its IsAsync property). Bind directly to an ImageSource property that is created (asynchronously) when the Binding calls the property getter. Don't use a binding converter, because that would not be called asynchronously.

Comment: Yes, I've figured why the binding converter wouldn't work, just thought that maybe there's was an asynchronous way of implementing it. I've already tried using asynchronous binding - I have added an example to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an asynchronous Binding for the `Source` property of the Image control in the ItemTemplate:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image Source="{Binding Image, IsAsync=True}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Since the `Image` property getter is now called in a background thread, the returned ImageSource must be made cross-thread accessible by freezing.

```
public class ImageItem
{
    private string url;

    public ImageItem(string url)
    {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get
        {
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            var buffer = new WebClient().DownloadData(url);

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
            {
                image.BeginInit();
                image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                image.StreamSource = stream;
                image.EndInit();
            }

            image.Freeze();
            return image;
        }
    }
}
```

---

The Image property might be written a little shorter by using `BitmapFrame` instead of `BitmapImage`. The `BitmapFrame.Create` method shown below already returns a frozen BitmapFrame.

```
public ImageSource Image
{
    get
    {
        var buffer = new WebClient().DownloadData(url);

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            return BitmapFrame.Create(
                stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works quite well. Is it because you are directly returning a frozen ImageSource instead of a byte array?

Comment: Yes exactly. When you return a byte array, the automatic conversion to ImageSource (i.e. creation of a BitmapFrame) still takes place in the UI thread. The solution presented here does as much as possible in a background thread.